# ServiceStack - Route Persons on Persons must start with a '/'

Tags: c#, routes, servicestack

I'm trying to auto register routes in ServiceStack using the following line as specified on wiki page https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Routing

```
Routes.AddFromAssembly(typeof(PersonsService).Assembly);
```

The program compiles but when I run it I get the error (Persons is my DTO):

```
Route Persons on Persons must start with a '/'
```

I searched for ServiceRoutesExtensions class on ServiceStack Git and imported in my solution. I  found it has the method

```
private static void AddRoute(this IServiceRoutes routes, Type requestType, string allowedVerbs)
```

I debugged this method and found that requestType parameter has no "/" before it; the signature of routes.Add from metadata is

```
IServiceRoutes Add(Type requestType, string restPath, string verbs);
```

So, restPath parameter is mapped to requestType.Name:

```
private static void AddRoute(this IServiceRoutes routes, Type requestType, string allowedVerbs)
    {
        routes.Add(requestType, requestType.Name, allowedVerbs);

        var hasIdField = requestType.GetProperty(IdUtils.IdField) != null;
        if (!hasIdField) return;

        var routePath = requestType.Name + "/{" + IdUtils.IdField + "}";
        routes.Add(requestType, routePath, allowedVerbs);
    }
```

I modified the method to be:

```
        private static void AddRoute(this IServiceRoutes routes, Type requestType, string allowedVerbs)
    {
        routes.Add(requestType, "/" + requestType.Name.ToLower(), allowedVerbs);

        var hasIdField = requestType.GetProperty(IdUtils.IdField) != null;
        if (!hasIdField) return;

        var routePath = "/" + requestType.Name.ToLower() + "/{" + IdUtils.IdField + "}";
        routes.Add(requestType, routePath, allowedVerbs);
    }
```

Now everything is working fine but I don't know if I missed something.

Answer (score 1):

This was a bug that was just [fixed with this commit](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/commit/6d852d6e816edfbcfd00fbf0b0494af788fc0596). Will be available in the next version of ServiceStack (v3.9.44+).

Comment: have you had a chance to push this fix to NuGet?